# Fantasy novel includes Amelia Earhart, pirates, desert island, captivating seashells

Tags: story-identification, novel

It starts out in an apartment building. The protagonist’s father is called into adjust the heating. When the protagonist enters the room, she assumes it’s because it’s too hot, but actually residents want to make it even warmer. There is a woman (Amelia Earhart, I think) with a seashell that basically enchants any male who hears it. What happened was that she landed on a deserted island, found the shell, and used that to call to people. It was really hot on the island and all men who came there eventually turned into lizards to survive the heat. Only one who did was a pirate who shrank into a smaller man and now wears black gloves.

There is a luxury liner and a woman who has a peanut allergy, there is an apartment with a glass floor, the resident saved a baby of the person below her by loudly tapping when it was about to chew on an electrical cord.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This could be *Olivia Kidney*

[image]

From [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/679465.Olivia_Kidney):

> Olivia Kidney's new apartment building is crazy. Talking lizards
>   crawling everywhere. A tropical rainforest growing in 7B. Even an
>   apartment made entirely of glass Maybe her father will get fired from
>   his job as the building super, and they can leave. But Olivia is tired
>   of moving from place to place, from school to school. What she
>   wouldn't give for a little slice of sanity.

Comment: Yes! That's it! :) I've been searching for it for ages. I can't believe it was found so fast :D

Comment: Sure! This is my first time using this site (I signed up just today!) How did you find the answer so fast!! *wondering*

Comment: @yulerule - Google skills! But I actually listened to this as an audiobook a long time ago, so I knew when I had found it. If you like my answer, you can upvote by clicking on the up arrow, and accept it by clicking on the checkmark beneath that. I hope you stay with us and continue to ask and answer questions.

Comment: I've tried googling this many times over the years, but could never find it. Out of sheer curiosity, what search terms did you use? I'd upvote but it says I don't have anough of a reputation

Comment: @yulerule - children's novel magic seashell apartment building. It's the second result. By the way, you now have enough reputation to upvote if you want. ;)